# Mongodb Aggregation : How to return only matching elements of an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In my mongoDB book collection I have documents structured as follow :

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("50485b89b30f1ea69110ff4c"),

  "publisher" : {
    "$ref" : "boohya",
    "$id" : "foo"
  },
  "displayName" : "Paris Nightlife",
  "catalogDescription" : "Some desc goes here",
  "languageCode" : "en",
  "rating" : 0,
  "status" : "LIVE",
  "thumbnailId" : ObjectId("50485b89b30f1ea69110ff4b"),
  "indexTokens" : ["Nightlife", "Paris"]
}
```

I perform the following regex query to find all documents having one indexToken starting with "Par" :

```
{ "indexTokens" : { "$regex" : "^Par" , "$options" : "i"}}
```

If I select only the indexTokens field to be returned like this :

```
{ "indexTokens" : 1}
```

The resulting DBObject is

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "50485b89b30f1ea69110ff4c"} , "indexTokens" : [ "Nightlife" , "Paris"]}
```

What I would like to get is ONLY the token / tag that matched the regex (I don0t care about retrieving the document at this point, neither do I need all the tags of the matched document)

Is this a case for the new Aggregation Framework relesed under MongoDB v2.2. ?

If yes how do I modify my query so that the actual result would look like :

{ "indexTokens" : ["Paris", "Paradise River", "Parma" , etc ....]}

Bonus question (do you has teh codez) : How do I do it using the Java driver ?

For now my java looks like :

```
DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("indexTokens", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^"+filter+"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
    BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("indexTokens",1);
    DBCursor curs = getCollection()
                    .find(query, fields)
                    .sort( new BasicDBObject( "indexTokens" , 1 ))
                    .limit(maxSuggestionCount);
```

Thx :)

EDIT:

As per your answers I modified my JAVA code as follow :

```
BasicDBObject cmdBody = new BasicDBObject("aggregate", "Book"); 
    ArrayList<BasicDBObject> pipeline = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>(); 

    BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("indexTokens", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^"+titleFilter+"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)));
    BasicDBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$indexTokens");
    BasicDBObject match2 = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("indexTokens", java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^"+titleFilter+"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)));
    BasicDBObject groupFilters = new BasicDBObject("_id",null);
    groupFilters.append("indexTokens", new BasicDBObject( "$push", "$indexTokens"));
    BasicDBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFilters);

    pipeline.add(match);
    pipeline.add(unwind);
    pipeline.add(match2);
    pipeline.add(group);

    cmdBody.put("pipeline", pipeline); 



    CommandResult res = getCollection().getDB().command(cmdBody);
    System.out.println(res);
```

Which outputs

```
{ "result" : [ { "_id" :  null  , "indexTokens" : [ "Paris"]}] , "ok" : 1.0}
```

This is genius !

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do this with the 2.2 aggregation framework. Something like this;

```
db.books.runCommand("aggregate", {
    pipeline: [
        {   // find docs that contain Par*
            $match: { "indexTokens" : { "$regex" : "^Par" , "$options" : "i"}},
        },
        {   // create a doc with a single array elemm for each indexToken entry
            $unwind: "$indexTokens" 
        },
        {   // now produce a list of index tokens
            $group: {
                _id: "$indexTokens",
            },
        },
    ],
})
```

Or this might be even closer to what you're after if you really want the array without the doc;

```
db.books.runCommand("aggregate", {
    pipeline: [
        {   // find docs that contain Par*
            $match: { "indexTokens" : { "$regex" : "^Par" , "$options" : "i"}},
        },
        {   // create a doc with a single array elemm for each indexToken entry
            $unwind: "$indexTokens" 
        },
        {   // now throw out any unwind's that DON'T contain Par*
            $match: { "indexTokens": { "$regex": "^Par", "$options": "i" } },
        },
        {   // now produce the list of index tokens
            $group: {
                _id: null,
                indexTokens: { $push: "$indexTokens" },
            },
        },
    ],
})
```

Comment: You can add this to your original answer as a second solution. This way people won't be confused why there are two answers from you :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you it works like a charm. I added an answer to show how I did it in JAVA (I don't have the latest driver so I couldnt use the aggregate() method on DBCollection.

Answer (score 5):

Building on the response from cirrus, I recommend doing the `$unwind` first to avoid the redundant `$match`.  Something like:

```
db.books.aggregate(
    {$unwind:"$indexTokens"},
    {$match:{indexTokens:/^Par/}},
    {$group:{_id:null,indexTokens:{$push:"$indexTokens"}}
})
```

How do you do this in Java?  You can use the [`DBCollection.aggregate(...)`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#aggregate%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject...%29) method of the MongoDB v2.9.0 driver.  Each pipeline operator, eg. `$unwind` or `$match`, corresponds to a `DBObject` object.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that $match is redundant. The trouble with $unwind is that it'll have to create a massive set of docs in RAM and you want to reduce that set down as early as possible. The first $match ensures that we're ONLY working with docs that even have Par* in the indexTokens before we unwind them. The second $match then cuts that set down to just the ones we want. Remember, you want to get your $match in early to reduce the pipeline volume.

Comment: You're right.  Weed out the non-matching documents, unwind the arrays, and then match again to weed out the documents that don't match the regular expression.