# Pymongo $regex in aggregate

Tags: regex, mongodb, pymongo

I want to use regex in the aggregation's pipeline.

I originally did:

```
regex = '(foo|bar)'
regexDB = re.compile(regex, re.I|re.U )

db.col.find({   
    'events.display': True,
    '$or' : [
        { 'events.description': regexDB } ,
        { 'events.title' : regexDB }
    ]
})
```

So I tried in the $match:

```
regex = '(foo|bar)'
regexDB = re.compile(regex, re.I|re.U )

db.col.aggregate([
    {'$unwind': "$events"},
    {'$match' :
        {
            'events.display' : True,
            '$or' : [
                { '$events.description': regexDB } ,
                { '$events.title' : regexDB }
            ]
        }
})
```

However it does not seem to work this way. The above code is based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4877662/1447885). I also found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12298311/1447885) for mongo's shell.

How can I perform regex in pymongo's aggregation?

Comment: it is not $events in the $or